# How do I create an event loop/message pipe in a console application?

Tags: c#, .net, event-loop

I would like to create an console application which has some events registered. The problem is that those events are never fired. In this particular situation in a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application I should invoke `Application.Run(new Form());` after registering those events, but it is `Console Application`.

So I would like to create an event loop or message pipe if it is possible for that console application.

The application:

```
using Bonjour;
using System;
using System.Threading;

using Bonjour;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication4 {
    class Program {
        [STAThread]

        static void Main() {

            DNSSDService service = new DNSSDService();
            DNSSDEventManager eventManager = new DNSSDEventManager();
            eventManager.ServiceFound += new _IDNSSDEvents_ServiceFoundEventHandler(eventManager_ServiceFound);
            DNSSDService browse = service.Browse(0, 0, "_axis-video._tcp", null, eventManager);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        static void eventManager_ServiceFound(DNSSDService browser, DNSSDFlags flags, uint ifIndex, string serviceName, string regtype, string domain) {
            Console.WriteLine("browser: " + browser + "\nDNSSDFlags " + flags + "\nifIndex " + ifIndex + "\nserviceName: " + serviceName + "\nregtype: " + regtype + "\ndomain: " + domain);

            DNSSDEventManager eventManager1 = new DNSSDEventManager();
            eventManager1.ServiceResolved += new _IDNSSDEvents_ServiceResolvedEventHandler(eventManager_ServiceResolved);
            browser.Resolve(flags, ifIndex, serviceName, regtype, domain, eventManager1);
        }


        private static void eventManager_ServiceResolved(DNSSDService service, DNSSDFlags flags, uint ifIndex, string fullname, string hostname, ushort port, TXTRecord record) {
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUND");
            Console.WriteLine("DNSSDService " + service + "\nDNSSDFlags " + flags + "\nifindex " + ifIndex + "\nfullname " + fullname + "hostname " + hostname + "\nport " + port + "\nrecord " + record);
            string s = record.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("mac " + record.GetValueForKey("macaddress"));

            var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(record.GetValueForKey("macaddress"));
            Console.WriteLine("mac " + str);
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

            DNSSDEventManager eventManager = new DNSSDEventManager();
            eventManager.AddressFound += new _IDNSSDEvents_AddressFoundEventHandler(eventManager_AddressFound);
            DNSSDAddressFamily family = new DNSSDAddressFamily();
            service.GetAddrInfo(flags, ifIndex, family, hostname, eventManager);
        }


        private static void eventManager_AddressFound(DNSSDService service, DNSSDFlags flags, uint ifIndex, string hostname, DNSSDAddressFamily addressFamily, string address, uint ttl) {
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(hostname);
            Console.WriteLine(address);
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
        }
    }
}

enter code here
```

#### WPF Main0Window.xaml.cs

```
namespace HomeSecurity {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            createGUI();
        }


        private void createGUI() {
            Scanner.ScanService();

            //THIS CODE WON'T RUN BECAUSE   Scanner.ScanService(); have frozen it
            AddVideoStream("192.168.0.2");
            AddVideoStream("192.168.0.2");
            AddVideoStream("192.168.0.2");
        }


        //TEN
        private void AddVideoStream(String sourceIP) {
            int cols = 2;
            int formsHostWidth = (int)(VideoPanel.ActualWidth / cols) - 4;

            WindowsFormsHost formsHost = new WindowsFormsHost();
            VideoStream videoStream = new VideoStream(sourceIP);
            formsHost.Width = formsHostWidth;
            formsHost.Height = videoStream.GetPrefferedHeight(formsHostWidth);
            formsHost.Child = videoStream;
            Border lineBorder = new Border();
            lineBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
            lineBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
            lineBorder.Child = formsHost;
            VideoPanel.Children.Add(lineBorder);
        }
    }
}
```

And the class Scanner which has method ScanService:

```
using Bonjour;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace HomeSecurity {
    class Scanner {
        [STAThread]
        public static void ScanService() {
            try {
                DNSSDService service = new DNSSDService();
                DNSSDEventManager eventManager = new DNSSDEventManager();
                eventManager.ServiceFound += new _IDNSSDEvents_ServiceFoundEventHandler(eventManager_ServiceFound);
                DNSSDService browse = service.Browse(0, 0, "_axis-video._tcp", null, eventManager);
                System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run(); // BLOCKS EVERYTHING
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");
            }
        }

        static void eventManager_ServiceFound(DNSSDService browser, DNSSDFlags flags, uint ifIndex, string serviceName, string regtype, string domain) {
            try {
                Console.WriteLine("---------------- eventManager_ServiceFound------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("browser: " + browser + "\nDNSSDFlags " + flags + "\nifIndex " + ifIndex + "\nserviceName: " + serviceName + "\nregtype: " + regtype + "\ndomain: " + domain);
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

                //   DNSSDService service2 = new DNSSDService();
                DNSSDEventManager eventManager1 = new DNSSDEventManager();
                eventManager1.ServiceResolved += new _IDNSSDEvents_ServiceResolvedEventHandler(eventManager_ServiceResolved);
                browser.Resolve(flags, ifIndex, serviceName, regtype, domain, eventManager1);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION--------eventManager_ServiceFound---------");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");
            }
         }

         private static void eventManager_ServiceResolved(DNSSDService service, DNSSDFlags flags, uint ifIndex, string fullname, string hostname, ushort port, TXTRecord record) {
             try {
                 Console.WriteLine("-------------------eventManager_ServiceResolved---------------------");
                 Console.WriteLine("DNSSDService " + service + "\nDNSSDFlags " + flags + "\nifindex " + ifIndex + "\nfullname " + fullname + "hostname " + hostname + "\nport " + port + "\nrecord " + record);
                 var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(record.GetValueForKey("macaddress"));
                 Console.WriteLine("mac " + str);
                 Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

                 //    DNSSDService service2 = new DNSSDService();
                 DNSSDEventManager eventManager = new DNSSDEventManager();
                 eventManager.AddressFound += new _IDNSSDEvents_AddressFoundEventHandler(eventManager_AddressFound);
                 DNSSDAddressFamily family = new DNSSDAddressFamily();
                 service.GetAddrInfo(flags, ifIndex, family, hostname, eventManager);
             }
             catch (Exception e) {

                 Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION--------eventManager_ServiceResolved---------");
                 Console.WriteLine(e);
                 Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");
             }
         }

         private static void eventManager_AddressFound(DNSSDService service, DNSSDFlags flags, uint ifIndex, string hostname, DNSSDAddressFamily addressFamily, string address, uint ttl) {
             try {
                 Console.WriteLine("------------------eventManager_AddressFound----------------------");
                 Console.WriteLine("hosname " + hostname);
                 Console.WriteLine("address " + address);
                 Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
             }
             catch (Exception e) {
                 Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----eventManager_AddressFound------------");
                 Console.WriteLine(e);
                 Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by event-loop or message pipe ? what are you trying to do and what part of your code doesn't work properly ?

Comment: Why do you have your using statements twice?

Comment: Couldn't you just throw a call at the bottom of your `Main` method to `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()`, using the overload that doesn't take any parameters?

Comment: Stop asking the same question over and over again.  You've essentially asked the exact same question 4 times within the last day.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand what your code sample has to do with events or Windows Forms. It looks like you're just using the [ZeroConf .NET libraries](http://craz.net/programs/ZeroconfNetServices/), which doesn't appear to have anything to with Windows forms or event loops?

At any rate, if you want to create (and pump) a windows message loop on a background thread, you can do it using the [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) dispatcher class - call `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()` from a background thread.

If you don't want to use WPF, you can use [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) - just call `Application.Run(someForm);`, but create `someForm` as a 0-width 0-height hidden window and set `ShowInTaskBar = false` on it, and that will create (and pump) a windows message loop too.

---

It looks like the ZeroConf libraries are COM objects, and the library is trying to post back to your main thread as it's using the [STA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#Threading) (Single-Threaded-Apartment) threading model.

Here's a guess. If the COM objects are set up to use 'Both' as their threading model, then they'll pick STA, because you're creating the objects on your main thread, and by default the main thread of a .NET app is `STAThread`.
Try deleting the [STAThread] attribute from your `Main` method, and putting an `[MTAThread]` attribute instead. If the ZeroConf COM objects are using 'Both' rather than STA as their threading model, then because you create them from an [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#Threading) thread, the events will be posted to arbitrary threadpool worker threads, instead of posted back to your main STA thread. 
If this is the case, this should solve it and you won't need to run a message loop at all. You'll have to write thread-safe code when processing your events though.

Comment: That is great what you are telling because the truth is I wanted to run this code in WPF application. How to do it with this CurrentDispatcher? Please help me I fight with it all day(12 hours). This is my previous attempt in WPF application : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100987/random-behaviour-of-the-wpf-application-after-adding-some-events-before-app-run?noredirect=1#comment31747477_21100987

Comment: Oops, sorry. It's a static `Dispatcher.Run()` method that you have to call on whatever thread you want to start pumping windows messages. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for help! The bad news is that I ended in the same place I started 12h ago. Please look at the edit in Original Post for you. Please have a glance at it. There is a method called `CreateGUI()` in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`  where I call `Scanner.ScanService()` nothing after it will be executed, because I added `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()` in `Scanner.ScanService()` method -> last qoute in the OP. **The events started to work fine... but rest of app is frozen.**

Thank you for your help, interest, time. Both methods are almost at the top of code block qoutes in OP.

Comment: Yes. The `Dispatcher.Run` method runs forever. The thread is now dedicated to processing windows messages. If you want it to do things, you can do it via posting messages to it and asking it to run some code, using `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

Answer (score 3):

I run event loop manually (instead of Console.ReadLine(); ) in the Main in such cases.

```
    public class User32Wrapper
    {
        // GetMessage
        [DllImport(@"user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool GetMessage(ref MSG message, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax);
        [DllImport(@"user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool TranslateMessage(ref MSG message);
        [DllImport(@"user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern long DispatchMessage(ref MSG message);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINT
        {
            long x;
            long y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MSG
        {
            IntPtr hwnd;
            public uint message;
            UIntPtr wParam;
            IntPtr lParam;
            uint time;
            POINT pt;
        }
    }

    private const int WM_CUSTOM_EXIT = 0x0400 + 2000;
    private const int WM_CUSTOM_1 = 0x0400 + 2001;
    private const int WM_CUSTOM_2 = 0x0400 + 2002;
    private const int WM_CUSTOM_3 = 0x0400 + 2003;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("Main");

        // running working threads
        ...

        // Main message loop
        User32Wrapper.MSG msg = new User32Wrapper.MSG();
        while (User32Wrapper.GetMessage(ref msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0))
        {
            if (WM_CUSTOM_EXIT == msg.message) // add WM_CLOSE if you need
            {
                break;
            }
            if (WM_CUSTOM_1 == msg.message)
            {
                onWmCustom1();
            }
            //if (check_any_message_you_need == msg.message)
            // you can for example check if Enter has been pressed to emulate Console.Readline();

            User32Wrapper.TranslateMessage(ref msg);
            User32Wrapper.DispatchMessage(ref msg);
         }

        log.Info("Finished");
    }
```

In the sample above console application will work untill (WM_USER+2000) message is received by main thread. So in another application (or in other thread in the same app) you need do like this:

```
    const int WM_CUSTOM_EXIT = WM_USER + 2000;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION* pInfo = ...;
    ::PostThreadMessageA(pInfo->dwThreadId, WM_CUSTOM_EXIT, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Looks like perfect fit for my idea of ScreenRecorder without any GUI, simply keyboard shotcuts - but how can I pass thread id between threads? Have any hints?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using external components, specifically if any of those components is COM, you really should be pumping, i.e. having a standard message loop running on your thread. Else things could get very ugly, but the details of it are awful and hidden in how .NET and COM work behind the scenes -- I can't say I understand that myself.

But, leaving all that uncertainty aside, have you tried creating a simple Sleep loop and avoid using hanging operations such as any Console.Read calls. Something like:

```
while( some condition )
{
    // Check if user pressed a key
    while (Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        // TODO: Read key
    }

    // Do some other processing maybe?

    // Sleep for 100 ms as to avoid spinning at 100% cpu
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Do the events come through then?